# How to modify CSS of ajax tool ValidatorCallout Extender

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I try to use the `ValidatorCallout` Extender from the asp.net Ajax site.
I have no idea on how to change the popup validator CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This extender has server `CssClass` property. Simply provide a class name of the CSS class in your markup.

```html
<style>
    .someClass {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<ajaxToolkit:ValidatorCalloutExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="ControlID" CssClass="someClass" />
```